# How To Get SQLException reason from SQLException Object

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I am using JDBC, and am running a query. Is there a way to get the reason it failed from the SQLException object returned?

In particular, I want to know if my query violated a foreign key constraint (and which one), or a key constraint.

Would this result be vendor-specific? Just in case, I am using the postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar driver. If it is vendor-specific, where would I find the codes?

EDIT: I want to do this dynamically - i.e.

```
if(violated foreign key constraint on attribute x) {
     return 5;
} else if (violated primary key constraint) {
     return 7;
} else {
     return 0;
}
```

Or something like that.

EDIT: According to [this post](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-jdbc/2003-02/msg00173.php), there are no vendor-specific error codes for  PostgreSQL JDBC. Dunno if that's still valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can process the error code from the SQLException object.

```
sqlException.getErrorCode()
```

This retrieves the **vendor-specific exception code** for this SQLException object. By using the vendor-specific error code, you can branch to the required block of code.

Comment: I tried looking for the codes for PSQL, but couldn't find them. Do you have a link?

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm#784) is the link for the PLSQL error codes

Answer (score 0):

try printing the stack trace (e is of SQLException type)

```
e.printStackTrace()
```

or getting the Message

```
e.getMessage()
```

These may give you some explanation of why the query failed

Comment: This is helpful, but I was looking for more dynamic (i.e. autonomous) ways to do this.